# How to read values in an array with multiple array values

Tags: php, arrays

I was trying to perform KMP pattern match with multiple patterns that can be stored in array but cannot got a clue in accessing values in an array.

I have a sentence say, 'hello this is me doing something'. I exploded by space and got an array of words and stored in a variable $pattern. Now I have an array with lenght 6, having six words. Now I am using str_split function on each index to get letter from it. Code is as follows

```
$a="hello this is me doing something";
$b=explode(" ",$a);
print_r ($b);
```

Got an output 
Array ( [0] => hello [1] => this [2] => is [3] => me [4] => doing [5] => something ) 
as expected
Then I tried splting each array using str_split function

```
$pattern=array();
for($i=0;$i<count($b);$i++){
    $pattern[$i]=str_split($b[$i]);
}
print_r($pattern);
```

I got following output

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => h [1] => e [2] => l [3] => l [4] => o ) [1] => Array ( [0] => t [1] => h [2] => i [3] => s ) [2] => Array ( [0] => i [1] => s ) [3] => Array ( [0] => m [1] => e ) [4] => Array ( [0] => d [1] => o [2] => i [3] => n [4] => g ) [5] => Array ( [0] => s [1] => o [2] => m [3] => e [4] => t [5] => h [6] => i [7] => n [8] => g ) )
```

Now I want every pattern to be different array which can be accessed and called separately. Like if I have [0] => Array ( [0] => h [1] => e [2] => l [3] => l [4] => o ) 
The expected output should be stored in different array variables dynamically.
How can I get this?

Comment: `print_r($pattern[0]);`?

Comment: Why can't you just access them from this multi-dimensional array that you already have instead of separate vars for each? I mean you could do something like `${'pattern' . $i}  = str_split(...);` which creates variables like `$pattern0` but it's a little messy.

Comment: @Jonnix: I don't have idea to do that. It is the reason

Comment: Well @u_mulder just showed you if that's all you need. You just access the key you're interested in.

Comment: @Jonnix: yeh that is what and how I was needing. Will perform it and come back here

Comment: And another hint here: although it certainly would be possible to separate those entries in the `$pattern` array into independent arrays it typically is a bad idea. Because you polute the name space of the scope without need.

Comment: I got the solution by taking hint from @Jonnix.. thanks